# How to have editable/draggable tags in select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to use [tagging](https://select2.org/tagging) feature of Select2 with the following code:

```
$('#tag_select').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: ['|'],
});
```

Although It allow me to add/remove tags, and modify the last one by hitting Backspace. However, I require to edit any previously added ones. Also it would be appreciated if I could reorder tags.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue in the Select2 project about how to do drag and drop sorting in 4 (as the previous method documented in 3 no longer works):

[Example "Select2 Drag and Drop Sorting" in Select2 4.0 · Issue #3004 · select2/select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3004)

In that discussion andrewbaldock gives this example of how you can use jQueryUI Sortable with Select2 4:

```
$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
  containment: 'parent'
});
```

There are drawbacks to this though because the Select2's value won't be wired up correctly. His full example explains how you can get around this limitation:

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewbaldock/ccj4twco/